# I run into three constant errors with VHDL program

Tags: vhdl

I just practicing a basic program in VHDL and keep getting three errors and don't seem to get a solution to them. The three errors are :

10028 Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "O" at question4.vhd(16)
10029 Constant driver at question4.vhd(15)
12153 Can't elaborate top-level user hierarchy

The code I used:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all

entity question4 is 
port( 
E : in std_logic;
I : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
O : out std_logic);
end question4;

architecture st1 of question4 is 
begin
O <= '0' when E = '0';
O <= I(0) or I(1) or ((not I(2)) and (not I(3))) when E = '1';


end st1;
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've done VHDL but I think the error is that you've got two lines of code that define O. Remember that `architecture`s run in parallel, not series, so you need to create one definition. It looks like errors 10029 and 12153 are downstream from 10028

Comment: @JakobLovern I would think the "when" would determine which O would be carried out for the value of E.

Comment: You might try `O <= E and (I(0) or I(1) or ((not I(2)) and (not I(3))))`.

Comment: VHDL isn't smart enough to do something like that unfortunately. If you're determined to use `when`, you should go for a when/else construct all on one line. [See this](https://insights.sigasi.com/tech/signal-assignments-vhdl-withselect-whenelse-and-case/)  for a good recipe

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is the following:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all

entity question4 is 
port( 
E : in std_logic;
I : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
O : out std_logic);
end question4;

architecture st1 of question4 is 
begin

O <= I(0) or I(1) or ((not I(2)) and (not I(3))) when E = '1' else '0';


end st1;
```

Comment: Concurrent assignment statements represent equivalent process statements. Every process statement containing a signal assignment has a driver for that signal. During signal update the value of a signal is taken from the resolution of all it's drivers. It's syntactically correct VHDL to have multiple drivers for resolved types. Here it's disallowed by synthesis tool semantics. Some vendor device families support multiple drivers when they can be semantically mapped to multiplexers.

Comment: I argue that it's still bad practice, even if it is allowed. Especially if the concurrent assignments are in different parts of the code, they could lead to a behaviour which is hard to understand. I don't even think they provide better readability *even* if one is before the other. I am working on a large code base and I am glad that ppl before me kept things straightforward and immediate to understand. :)

Comment: Your introductory comment regarding syntax is not valid noting the original two concurrent assignment statements neither resolve the desired output nor meets the used synthesis tool's semantic requirement. Your opinion on what constitutes bad practice appears non-sequitar.